# I can't response a window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction() vb.net

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm try to create a custom page to upload files from the CKEditor, but i'm get the following error

[image: captura]

[image: captura]

[image: captura]

I'm using thist code in vb.net

```
Dim Mensaje As String = ""
Mensaje = "<scr" + "ipt type='text/javascript'> window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + funcNum + ", '" + url + "', '')</scr" + "ipt>"
Response.Write(Mensaje)
```

My config.js file:

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2018, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
     config.language = 'es';
     //config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;
     config.uiColor = '#FFFFFF';
     config.height = 500;
     config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/Pages/HE/SHE00000/UploadCKEditorFiles.aspx?type=Files';
     config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/Pages/HE/SHE00000/UploadCKEditorFiles.aspx?type=Image';
     config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/Pages/HE/SHE00000/UploadCKEditorFiles.aspx?type=Flash';

     config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'undo', 'clipboard' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
        { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
        { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
        { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
        { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
        { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
        { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
        { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
    ];

    config.removeButtons = 'PasteFromWord,Templates,About,Save,Form,Iframe';
};
```

I don't know how this wait that I response to get a valid response.

If i run de code in the console, it's run OK, but if I use the response.write I get that error.

I read [this tutorial](https://www.pluginsforckeditor.com/Tutoriales/86/Subir-ficheros-con-CKEditor/es/n86.aspx) for do this.

> Details:

Browser: Chrome 65 & Firefox 59

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro

CKEditor version: 4.9.1

The issue in Github is this: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/1894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in Github is solved: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/1894

Comment: Absolutely. And here are the essensials explaining what so many people are searching for. [link to explanation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_upload.html#response-file-uploaded-successfully)